# Chat makes old per-site meta links HTTPS and broken

Tags: bug, chat, per-site-meta, ssl, onebox

I was looking at an old chatroom when I found a link from a feed that was from before per-site metas switched from `meta.%.stackexchange.com` to `%.meta.stackexchange.com`. This link, however, was changed to HTTPS by whatever oneboxes the things. These redirect links *are not HTTPS*; my browser (Firefox) says it's a security risk and a bunch of scary things.

**Can this be fixed, either so Chat oneboxing fixes old links to per-site metas, or by making it so that the redirect pages such as `meta.scifi` to `scifi.meta` (and by extension others like `fantasy.scifi`) work with HTTPS?**

Comment: ugh, there's no good way to fix those AFAIK. You'd probably need mod access too. Might be worth figuring out what needs fixing somehow, document those links (on google docs?) and see if folks can put in the time to go edit those.

Comment: Just fyi: We cannot make the *.sitename links work with HTTPS. It requires adding every single subdomain to a certificate which is a very large maintenance task and we've repeatedly said we would never consider doing.

Comment: @animuson Did you consider using [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) and letsencrypt? I think it could solve all these tasks quite easily on zero cost.